# putSerializableでActivityを保存して使いたい

Tags: android, fragment

`Fragment`に`Activity`のインスタンスを渡そうとしており、`newInstance`メソッドでは以下のようにしました。

```
    public static DailyFragment newInstance(Activity activity){
        DailyFragment dailyFragment = new DailyFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("activity", new Object[]{ activity });
        dailyFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return dailyFragment;
    }
```

そして`Activity`を復元するときは以下のようにしました。

```
    (Activity)getArguments().getSerializable("activity")
```

しかし「`java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`」とエラーが出てしまいます。
どうすれば`newInstance`内で`putSerializable`を使って`Activity`を保存して使うことができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
エラーの内容はObjectの配列はActivityにはキャストできないと出てますね。
これはできません。ActivityはあくまでObjectの子ですから。

また、Activity自身がSerializableを実装していないのでputSerializableで取得
はできないと思います。Parcelableも実装していないです。

Activityの何を具体的には保存したいのでしょうか？
Activityの状態を保存するのでしたら、onSaveInstanceStateで取得できるbundle自身を
bundleに格納する事もできます。bundleにbundleを入れる事もできますよ。

参考になると嬉しいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。onSaveInstanceStateですか。ちょっとこちらを使用してみたいと思います。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

`serialize`出来るのは`Serializable`インターフェースを実装(`implements`)したクラスのみです。
`Activity`クラスは`Serializable`インターフェースを実装していないため、`putSerializable`できません。
たとえ、`Activity`が`Serializable`を実装していたとしても、`getSerializable`した時点で別のインスタンスになってしまいます。

なぜ`Activity`のインスタンスが必要なのでしょうか？
`Fragment`で`getActivity()`するのではダメですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Serializableの使い方がイマイチわかっていませんでした。。。
FragmentでgetActivityをするとnullになってしまったので、Activityからインスタンスを渡してもらおうと思ってこのような実装にしています。